# can't add task to userstory when using filter in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

1) In TFS project, go to work-->User story-->backlog. there is a 'plus' sign for the current select user story. it can be used to add task under user story.
[the plus sign is displayed to enable crate task for user story.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK3Cn.png)

2) try filter userstory, like filtering user story by state 'new'. then, as the filter result is displayed, there is no 'plus' sign displayed now?
[there is no 'plus' sign now, it is as designed? thanks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp5Vm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, it's by design.

Actually the filter is like a query, it has the same behavior with query.

However the requirement makes sense, I have submitted a [**User Voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33894328-add-the-plus-sign-to-add-task-for-user-story-whe) for you to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

Comment: @zhuang Is the reply answered your question? Is it helpful for you?